# Stop reactive event chain

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am working with `shiny` for `R`. At the beginning of my program I am creating a `dataframe` that is stored in `reactiveValues()` .

```
myReactiveDataframe <- reactiveValues()
myReactiveDataFrame[["df"]] <- someDataFrame
```

Upon interaction with the App through the user content of the dataframe is modified and then stored in `reactiveValues()` as well.
Something like

```
myReactiveDataframe[["modified"]] <- myReactiveDataFrame$df[MyReactive....]
```

Later on in my App I have some `observe()` that work with `myReactiveDataframe$modified`. 
My Problem is: On the start of the App `myReactiveDataframe$modified` evaluates to `NULL` because it is not created yet. That means that many of the `observers` get triggered and crash of course because the input is `NULL` and not a dataframe. To prevent that I have to write a `if/else` at the beginning of each `observe` that checks if the variable of interest `is.null(...`. 
Very annoying. Any ideas how not to do that?

Comment: That is the **exact purpose** for `observeEvent` (see [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html)). In `observeEvent`, you can specify an expression and the observe goes off **only if** the expression is **not** evaluating to `NULL`.

Comment: I could give an `reactiveValue` to an `observeEvent`? Its not only for the `ui` -> `input$userClick`

Comment: Quote from the exact page I linked above, describing what can be used as event expression: "A (quoted or unquoted) expression that represents the event; this can be a simple reactive value like input$click, a call to a reactive expression like dataset(), or even a complex expression inside curly braces."